# discordpy как ловить записи с аудита?

Tags: python, discord.py, бот

Хочу создать канал аудита на своём дискорд сервере и мне нужно как то отслеживать действия по типу бана, мута, кика и т.д

Допустим админ удалил сообщения от человека и в отведённый канал выводится что то такое:

[image: Пример]

Обычно все записи о таких действиях появляются в настройках сервера - записях журнала аудита.
Бот умеет их считывать но у меня не получается сделать считывание постоянным, получается только командой.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого существуют события (event). Допустим вы хотите, чтобы в канал аудита присылались сообщения о том, что бот или админ (или вообще любой пользователь) удалил какое-то сообщение. Тогда описываем событие `on_message_delete(message)` или `on_raw_message_delete(payload)`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_message_delete(message):
#ваш код
```

Это событие будет вызываться каждый раз когда какое-то сообщение было удалено. Подобные события есть и для кика и для бана. Все нужные вам события можете найти [здесь](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_raw#event-reference)